# jQuery .next() next not working when inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery

After seeing my questions replied here and with success, the problems appeared when transposing to my script:
I have a dropdown that is being cloned which shows it's value on a side div. The problem is that when I clone it, the dropdown below don't work and the first updates all the remaining. Code:

Add

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="products-row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 nopadding">
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <input type="text" id="number1" class="form-control" value="1" />
            </div>
            <!-- if i remove the div below and leave only the select, it works -->
            <div class="col-xs-6" >
                <select name="total-checkout" id="name" class="form-control product-name select" >
                    <option value="25" >A</option>
                    <option value="50" >B</option>
                    <option value="75" >C</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-2">
                <div class="tags">25</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var count = 0;

$('#add-more').click(function(){

var id = $(".row:last").attr('id');
var appendDiv = $($(".products-row:last")[0].outerHTML);
    appendDiv.attr('id', ++id).insertAfter(".products-row:last");        
});

$('#name').change(function(event) {
$('.tags').html($('#name').val());
});
$(document).on('change', '.select', function() {
    $(this).next(this).html($(this).val());
});
```

Working jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QuadDamage/p843nc9j/

If I remove the `<div class="col-xs-6">` from around the `<select>` the output will appear not formatted but correctly updating the div.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .next only looks at siblings, not cousins or aunts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're targeting `.col-xs-2 .tags` if this is the case you need this code

```
$(this).parent().next().find('.tags').html($(this).val());
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I really need to step up my jQuery! Thanks!